# How does YAML Interpret Special Characters

Tags: parsing, syntax, yaml

So, I'm attempting to write a plugin configuration file in YAML, but my parser is throwing errors even though everything *seems* to be formatted correctly. The YAML website is less than helpful, and the only place I've found a tutorial of any kind is the spotty one at docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html. Since I am probably missing something silly in the syntax from a general lack of YAML syntax knowledge, what do each of the YAML special characters do?

For reference, here is my misbehaving YAML file:

```
EnforcedWorlds:|
  - World
  - Nether
  - DIM-1
  - End
  - DIM1
Ignore List:|
  - CuckooClock5000
  - Venomous Potato
  - Subtle Snail
Radius: 10
DisallowInRadius:|
  - Sandstone => "Darude Sandstone!"
  - Quarry (1040) => "This block is too L33T 4U 2 Use here :)"
  - Minium Stone (20102 with datavalues 1 to 1520) => "Minimum Minium area!"
Command Output groups:
  Mod:|
    - Perm Node: gpu.mod
    - (Light Green) $(Banner)
    - (Teal) Command A
    - (Pink) Command B
  Admin:|
    - Perm Node: gpu.admin
    - (Light Red) $(Banner)
    - Mod lines 2-3
    - (Blue) Command C
    - (Bold)
  Owner:|
    - Mod lines 1-3
    - Admin line 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your YAML syntax is invalid not because of the characters, but because of missing spaces:

```
EnforcedWorlds:|
```

This whole line is a string. You want it to be a mapping key (`EnforcedWorlds`), followed by a header for a block scalar (`|`). For this to work, you *must* add a space after the colon:

```
EnforcedWorlds: |
```

But I am not sure if that is actually what you want. It will parse all following more indented lines as a literal string (preserving newlines). But the content looks like a YAML sequence, so perhaps you want to write it like this:

```
EnforcedWorlds:
  - World
  - Nether
  - DIM-1
  - End
  - DIM1
```

Here, the value will be parsed as a sequence of scalar items.

To see how your input is parsed, you can use some web services:

- http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/ (YAML 1.2 reference parser)
- http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ (PyYAML)
- http://flyx.github.io/NimYAML/testing.html (NimYAML)

There's also [ysh](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML-Shell/bin/ysh), an interactive YAML shell for testing, using Perl.

Comment: Please note that the  PyYAML online parser is PyYAML 1.1

Answer (score 21):

YAML doesn't require quoting most strings but you'll want to quote special characters if they fall within a certain list of characters.  Use quotes if your value includes any of the following special characters:  `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `&`, `*`, `#`, `?`, `|`, `-`, `<`, `>`, `=`, `!`, `%`, `@`, `:` also `` ` `` and `,`

- [YAML Spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#53-indicator-characters)